# Multiple conditions to apply to each row - code improvement

Tags: r, code-cleanup, multiple-conditions

i have this table:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F
a   1   0   1   1   1   1
b   2   0   1   1   1   1
c   1   0   0   1   1   1
d   1   0   0   0   1   1
e   2   0   0   0   1   1
f   1   0   0   0   1   1
g   2   1   1   1   1   1
h   2   0   0   1   0   1
i   1   0   0   1   1   1
j   1   0   0   0   1   1
```

i would like to create a new column which would show B if from B to F the first "1" encountered was in B. Or "C" if the first "1" encountered was in C, and so on.. I've written some code to do this and i ask if this can be written better.

```
test <- read.table("sof2.txt")

test$summary <- NA
test$summary <- ifelse(test$B == 1, test$summary <- "B", 
                     ifelse (test$B == 0 & test$C == 1, test$summary <- "C", 
                             ifelse (test$B == 0 & test$C == 0 & test$D == 1, test$summary <- "D",
                                     ifelse (test$B == 0 & test$C == 0 & test$D == 0 & test$E == 1, test$summary <- "E",
                                             ifelse (test$B == 0 & test$C == 0 & test$D == 0 & test$E == 0 & test$F == 1, test$summary <- "F", NA)))))
```

wanted table:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   summary
a   1   0   1   1   1   1   C
b   2   0   1   1   1   1   C
c   1   0   0   1   1   1   D
d   1   0   0   0   1   1   E
e   2   0   0   0   1   1   E
f   1   0   0   0   1   1   E
g   2   1   1   1   1   1   B
h   2   0   0   1   0   1   D
i   1   0   0   1   1   1   D
j   1   0   0   0   1   1   E
```

Comment: Have a look at `cut()`

Comment: Check out dplyr's `case_when`

Answer (score 4):

We can use `max.col`

```
df1$summary <- names(df1)[-1][ max.col(df1[-1] > 0, 'first')]
df1$summary
#[1] "C" "C" "D" "E" "E" "E" "B" "D" "D" "E"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), 
    B = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), C = c(1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), D = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), E = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L), F = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", 
"e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"))
```